# I am facing issue thread related issue in asp.net core identity in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

Error Message :A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext

```
 public async Task<UserSearchDto> GetSingle(string userId, string baseUrl)
        {
            
            var user =await  _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user != null)
            {
                UserSearchDto userSearches = new UserSearchDto
                {
                    data
                };
                return userSearches;
            }
        }
```

In above service FindByIdAsync throwing this exeption

while i am debugging step by step then i am not facing this error

my setup in startup file as below

```
services.AddTransient<IAuthService, AuthService>();
```

Even i changed above service method but its not working
why it requires more time to perform or there is any another issue?

Edit

these manager are passed in service

```
 private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
 private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
```

this is ctor

```
public AuthService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager,
            RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager,
            IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
        {
            this._userManager = _userManager;
            this._roleManager = _roleManager;
        }
```

User manage and role manager are used from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

```
 services.AddDbContext<Db>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(mySqlConnectionStr);
            }
            );
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. It seems like you're not following the typical design patterns (proper registering of dependency injection) please give a [mcve].

Comment: I made simple design where I am calling UserManager<Application User> and role manager as Private like DB and passing them in ctor  and using as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The DbContext has a scoped service lifetime, coupled to an asp.net request. Thus services using the context should preferably also have a scoped service lifetime.

Comment: i marked service as scoped also i am facing same issue

Comment: the thing is when i am debugging every time i am getting result but without debugging I am facing same issue

Comment: @AshwaniBhardwaj in that case, we'll definitely need a [mcve].

Comment: question is updated

Comment: @AshwaniBhardwaj why are you using scoped? I've represent you a solution

Comment: here what you have passed in UsermanagerContext  My db context ?

Comment: i checked yout method also its same using efcore find async so i am getting result but why usermanager is not providing result

Comment: @IKomarovLeonid  i checked your solution  is there any another approach because            await using var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<db>();
is calling whole database can i call just requred table or is there any model which i can paas as parameter?

Comment: @AshwaniBhardwaj I do not see much problem with that. It is better that create different db's for each requests

Answer (score -2):

I can recommend you such approach (TModel can be yours UserSearchDto):

```
    // Or your db context directly in class but this is better
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _factory;
    
    public async Task<TModel> FindByIdAsync(ulong id)
    {
         using var scope = _factory.CreateScope();
         // your context gets here
         await using var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManagerContext>();
         // this is important
         var entities = userManager.Set<TModel>().AsNoTracking();
         // data should be filled after FindByIdAsync(ulong id), not in this method
         return await entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);
    }
```

Comment: Wut? Service scope? That means that you're calling it from a singleton. That's just bad design

Comment: @JHBonarius I don't think so. Maybe for you it is better to say that "search by id method" should not fill any data to search result inside this method, but yeah it is definetly better to say  that service scope factory is a bad design. Looks strange. Trashient looks like bad design almost everywhere

Comment: @JHBonarius 
Transient
since they are created every time they will use more memory & Resources and can have the negative impact on performance
use this for the lightweight service with little or no state.

Comment: Yes.... so what's in the middle? The DbContext is a scoped service, so this repository service should also be.

Comment: JHBonarius It helpless discussion what kind of repository should author registered. It is more important to solve his issue. I've provide the example how to avoid his problem.

Comment: But this is not a good fix. It's a hack